# React Native Build App build error type a.a is defined multiple times

Tags: android, react-native, mobile, apk, zoom-sdk

I am working on a react native project where I had to integrate zoom video sdk in it. First I was working on zoom version 1.2.0, then I had to upgrade it to 1.5.3. after upgrading it the app build and work fine in debug mode, but when I tried to generate an app or do a bundle release it's returning this error.

`* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskDelegate
> There was a failure while executing work items
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingWorkAction
> > com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while merging dex archives:
> Type a.a is defined multiple times: /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/healing-center-mobile/android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/mergeExtDexRelease/classes.dex, /Users/macbookpro/Desktop/healing-center-mobile/android/mobilertc/build/.transforms/e16cb3969562dbd5409148a5e09af52c/transformed/jetified-mobilertc-runtime/classes.dex
> Learn how to resolve the issue at https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.`

I search for it and there where many solutions like adding
 `dependenciesInfo { // Disables dependency metadata when building APKs. includeInApk = false // Disables dependency metadata when building Android App Bundles. includeInBundle = false }` in app/build.gradle

or add `multiDexEnabled true` and `implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'`

or add the exclude model to the project in app/build.gradle  `implementation (project(':mobilertc')) { exclude module: 'duplicated module' }`

or by adding to build.gradle  `implementation("com.google.guava:guava:24.0-jre")`

I also tried to invalidate caches from android, delete node modules and install it again.
But always the same error.
So anyone can help with it?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue.

In android/app/build.gradle

remove this line:

implementation 'us.zoom.videosdk:ZoomVideoSDK:1.5.3'

Build again => Solved this problem

Hope it helpful

Comment: i Don't even have this in android/app/build.gradle